# How to set header in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am working on authentication in nodeJs.I have created successfully login API and it works well on the postman.I stuck on client side.It does not set token on headers.I am using the passport,jwt for authentication.My code is

```
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  var name = {
    name: req.body.name,
    password: req.body.password
  }
  // let m = '';
  // console.log(name)
  request({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/login",
    method: "POST",
    json: true,   // <--Very important!!!
    body: name
  }, function (error, response) {
    if (response.body.error == true) {
      req.flash('errorMsg', response.body.message);
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    else {

      // localStorage.setItem('token', response.body.token);
      // console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
      // req.headers['authorization'] = response.body.token;
      // res.setHeader('authorization', response.body.token);
      // req.session['token'] = response.body.token;
      // console.log(req.session['token'])
      // res.set({
      //    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      //    'authorization':response.body.token
      //   });
      //   res.setHeader('authorization', response.body.token);
      //   req.headers['authorization'] = response.body.token;


      res.redirect('/secret');
      next();
    }
  });
  // console.log(m);
});
```

and my middleware is:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  var token = req.body.token || req.session['token'] || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || localStorage.getItem('token');
  req.headers['authorization'] = token;
  console.log(req.session['token'], token)
  console.log(req.headers['authorization'], config.jwtSecret);
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, config.jwtSecret, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {

        res.json({
          'message': 'Failed to authenticate user'
        });
      } else {
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    // logger.warn('Unauthorized');
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }
  console.log(req.headers['authorization'])
});
```

I have tried all possible to set the token in headers but it didn't work well.If I get my token on app.use middleware then I can verify token easily but it didn't allow to set my token.
How can I do this??

Comment: did you find an answer for this @nitin

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting headers for request module like

> request({ url: "http://localhost:3000/api/login", method: "POST", json: true, // <--Very important!!! body: name ,
>   headers: {'x-access-token':token}}